# How to add an EMR Spark Step?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr

According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-submit-step.html):

> For Step type, choose Spark application.

But in Amazon EMR -> Clusters -> mycluster -> Steps -> Add step -> Step type, the only options are:

[image]

Comment: what version of emr and which region?

Comment: @Lamanus region=eu-central-1

Comment: @Lamanus where can I see my EMR version?

Comment: The emr image version something like emr-5.29.0 or emr-6.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a Spark Application option because I created a Core Hadoop cluster.

When I created the cluster, under Software configuration, I should have chosen Spark, then I would have had the Spark application option under Step type.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to add EMR spark steps:

**- Using [command-runner.jar](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-commandrunner.html) (custom application)** 
[image]

```
spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi /usr/lib/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples.jar 10
```

**Using aws cli to do the same**

```
aws emr add-steps --cluster-id j-xxxxxxxx --steps Name="add emr step to run spark",Jar="command-runner.jar",Args=[spark-submit,--class,org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi,/usr/lib/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples.jar,10]
```

**- Spark Application** 
[image]

Comment: I am sure he world have found that. The question is about from the drop down list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use command-runner.jar for your use case. For the step type let it be Custom Jar from the options that you have.
Check out this image for detail.

[image: command-runner usage]

You can read more about command-runner.jar [command-runner-usage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-commandrunner.html)